# How can unit quaternions represent attitude?

Tags: quaternions

I'm reading a paper the presents a quaternion based complimentary filter but I'm confused on how and why they represent the attitude of an object with a single quaternion denoted by "q" in the paper. I thought that a unit quaternion represents a rotation like a rotation matrix and is defined as an operator. For example to rotate a vector v... v_f=q(v_0)q^-1

In the paper they state "If the device has an attitude q at time t, the attitude at the subsequent time-step t + dt, is denoted q′"

How can an object have an attitude q?

Answer (score 0):

They probably misuse the word attitude. What they mean by attitude is the orientation of an object.

The orientation is usually defined in physics as a frame made of three orthogonal vectors.

You can also define the orientation as a rotation matrix but that forces you to choose a coordinate system. Other way is to use a quaternion, which is an algebraic entity like a vector (and thus coordinate-free).

Hope that helps.